# Browser crashed - tickboxes array to Ajax (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When I click on the Add button, the browser (chrome) crashed.

I am trying to send the array of tickboxes (value) to ajax (PHP).

See the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="0"> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1"> Medium
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2"> Large
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3"> X-Large

<input id="ButtonAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#ButtonAdd").click(function() {  
  var optionsz = $("input:checkbox[name='option\\[\\]']");
  $.post("ajax.php", { optionsz:optionsz },
   function(data)  {
     console.log(data)
   });
 });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: After commenting out/uncommenting lines to see if you can determine where the error is occuring, what did you find out? If you haven't tried that yet, go ahead and do that and let us know what happens.

Comment: I did and it was causing from ajax. I have removed the ajax code and it work.. I don't understand why..

Comment: Now try and comment out the `console.log` to see if that is causing it. If not, try commenting out and replacing the `var optionsz` line with `var optionsz = "";`. See if you can narrow down the **exact** line that's causing it.

Comment: I have tried comment out `console.log` and still causing problem.. Then I've tried replacing `var optionsz` to `var optionsz = ""`; and it work.. so in that case how do i past array of tickboxes to `optionsz` hmmm

Comment: Excellent debugging. You narrowed down the problem and found the solution (with some help below). You'll be much better at tracking down problems in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send a jQuery object `optionsz` but what you really want to do is serialize the form in which the options reside and send that to the ajax.php script.

```
var optionsz = $(your form).serialize();
```

Comment: How to do without serialize the form?

Comment: why wouldn't you want to serialize the form? You could build a string manually by looping over the inputs `option[]=foo&option[]=bar&option[]=baz` but serialize is much cleaner